# azure blob storage classes to python dictionaries?

Tags: python-3.x, azure-blob-storage

this sounds like it should be simple but im having a terrible time here.

Im using the azure python sdk, latest version. I'm able to reach the endpoint, get data etc.... but things come down in azure custom classes. In the end they are mostly just dictionaries but some formatting is messed up. Like an entry in the dict, rather than an actual date, it comes back as a "datetime.datetime(2021, 05....etc.

I've been trying to parse and fix these things but I feel like there should be a better way. Now im onto a blob storage class that contains multiple sub dicts. I'm trying to detect if the value in the kv pair is a dict, but instead the type is " <class 'azure.storage.blob._models.ContentSettings'> ". I'm not that familiar with Azure, is there a way to return the data in these classes as actual python dicts?

If not, is there a way for me to use isinstance on something like  <class 'azure.storage.blob._models.ContentSettings'> ?

thx.

Comment: So are you looking for a way to get blob properties(such as `last_modified`) by storage blob SDK V12?

Comment: yes.. im actually getting all blobs in all containers and making a large jsonlist from python dicts. and if i blindly parse the azure classes as dicts and they are, it works fine. container_client = blob_service_client.get_container_client( (container_name) ) blob_list = container_client.list_blobs().  I'm basically looking at the output and then strategically parsing the dicts as I see them. but thats bad cuz if a new property comes up i dont have today.... it'll break.

Comment: if it all came down in nice dicts as-is i could just output it and be happy

Comment: How's going? Has your issue get resolved?

Comment: im out today til later this afternoon. will pick it up again then. thanks for the response below. I never thought about parsing each things individually, but isnt it technically the same thing? I have a lot more data when I pull back things including the items you posted. If I have to know each item rather than just "give it all to me in json" its sorta the same as what im doing now which is adding handling for each nested dict. in your example, print(type(blob) and see what each is. it parses like a dict but isnt defined as one. ouput for several fields isnt json friendly. like the bytearray

Answer (score 0, accepted):

best method i could work up for now as to create a function to pass all received kv pairs to and format them, if need be, then returned the formatted version and add it to the new dict.

i do a check on each pair to see if the value in the pair has a .items() possibility, if so it runs that set through the formatting function.

I feel like theres a better way but for now it seems this gets me an output that is readable and json friendly.

The formatter function looks like this.

```
def formatAzureSpecialChars(self, k, v) -> list:
    if k == 'encryption_scope' or k == 'blob_type':
        v = str(v)
        v.replace("'", "")
        v = str(v)
        return(True, v)
    elif isinstance(v, datetime.datetime):
        v = v.strftime("%Y-%m-%d_T%H-%M-%S")
        return(True, v)
    elif k == 'content_md5':
        v = v.hex()
        return(True, v)
    else:
        return(False, v)
```